# Running an app based on google play services library

Tags: android, eclipse, api, location, google-play-services

I am trying to learn about Android Location API using Google Play Services through ANDROIDHIVE but whenever I try to run the app in genymotion the app never starts. I have checked every other apps developed by me they run perfectly and even my location API app runs when I remove the google-play-services-lib from the app through the properties. It only does not run when I add this library . I am using eclipse and the tutorial is also for eclipse users and my genymotion version is 2.4

Comment: No errors .. it doesn't run at all .. not even a prompt to show what device i might want to run it.. i have to do it manually through run configuraton ... i tried removing all java codes except the necessary ones in main activity .. added the library and still it won't run

Answer (score 0):

@Saud kindly double check your set up with your API/s. There are many factors to consider why your app doesn't run. Emulator must run Android 4.2.2 or higher. Check the [guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) to see if you have followed the steps on setting up the Google Play services to your project. Also, take note that Google Play Services need to be sideloaded in Genymotion.

Comment: I am checking your link. What about the emulator created from the AVD manager? Do they need to be side loaded as well ?

Comment: Try doing both as for testing purposes.